# make layout that overlay above google map fragment in android

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout

I need to make LinearLayout that overflow an android google map
as shown in this image any one has any idea how to make this 
I need help ? 
[android google map and linearlayout above it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rKeR8.jpg)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try use `FrameLayput`

```
<FrameLayout...>

   <MapFragment.../>

   <LinearLayout...>

   // your layout

   </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks alot. This works like a charm. is there another way to do that . can I merge any layouts I need in this FramLayout like other relativeone according to map.

Comment: I can't upvote your answer because my reputation is less than 15 :))

Comment: I did this, but when I try linearlayout.visibility = gone, then the map moves, how can I avoid the map to move when changing views rules???

Answer (score 0):

You can use RelativeLayout as parent layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/mapFragment"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/topLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottomLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I uses this first answer but your answer used it as the layout inside framelayout. Thanks for help.